# Why Integer.parseInt(args[0]) doesn't work on Eclispse but this code works on Console?

Tags: eclipse, console, indexoutofboundsexception, parseint

```
public class SumTwoNumbers {

    public static void main(String args[])

    {
        int number1,number2,sum;
        
        
        System.out.println("Enter first number");
        number1= Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        
        System.out.println("Enter first number");
        number2=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        
        sum=number1+number2;
        
        System.out.println(sum);
        
        
        }

}
```

Error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at java_basics.SumTwoNumbers.main(SumTwoNumbers.java:12)
****This was done using Eclipse****

```
public class Addtonumber

{

public static void main(String args[])

{

int a,b,c;
a=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
b=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
c=a+b;
System.out.println(c);
}

}
```

**but the above code worked using Console.
Why is it not working with Ecslipse**

Comment: In Eclipse in the run configuratio in the _Arguments_ tab in the _Program arguments_ field you have to specify at least two numbers.

Comment: the numbers are supposed to entered by the users

Comment: `args[0]` is the first argument, with which the application is started, not something that is read from the console while the application is running. If you want to get prompt for these two numbers enter `${string_prompt} ${string_prompt}` in the _Program arguments_ field in the run configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You must specifiy the arguments in Eclipse.
Here is the first tutorial I found about this topic: https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/cmd.pdf